# Custom datasource in CakePHP not working

Tags: cakephp, model, datasource

I’m trying to create a custom datasource for Amazon Web Services in CakePHP. My approach is as follows:

- Base `AwsDataSource` that creates signatures, makes the actual HTTP requests etc
- Various datasources for each AWS product (i.e. S3, SQS etc) that extend this class and specifies the endpoint to use
- Models for things like `S3Bucket`, `SqsQueue`, `SqsMessage` and so on

My base datasource class looks like this (simplified):

```
<?php
class AwsDataSource extends DataSource {

    public $config = array(
        'key' => '',
        'secret' => '',
        'region' => ''
    );
    public $endpoint;

    public function signRequest($parameters) {
        // generates signature
    }

    public function makeRequest($parameters = array(), $method = 'get') {
        // generates signature and makes HTTP request to AWS servers
    }
}
```

And a sample model looks like this:

```
<?php
class SqsQueue extends AwsAppModel {

    public $name = 'SqsQueue';
    public $useTable = false;
}
```

My problem comes trying to then use these models/datasources in my CakePHP app.

I’ve implemented methods named `create()`, `read()`, `update()` and `delete()` in my AWS datasource as per [the CakePHP cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html#an-example), but they don‘t seem to be getting called. I know this because I’ve put `die()` statements in my datasource with a message, and execution is never stopped.

I’ve exhausted the cookbook, so if any one could show me how to get my models to call the CRUD methods in my datasource classes then I’d be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Turns out my approach was flawed.

The datasource is specified in database config and is specified as `AwsDataSource`. Therefore, `S3DataSource` or `SqsDataSource` is never used, even though that’s where I’ve defined my CRUD methods, hence my application never exiting (because the CRUD methods aren’t defined in `AwsDataSource`, the actual datasource being called).

Looks like it’s back to the drawing board.